# Text search - mongodb

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, text-search

I am using mongo text search in my application.

#### Index:

```
db.test.createIndex(
    {
        title: 'text',
        description: 'text'
    },
    {
        name: "TextIndex",
        weights: {
           title: 10,
           description: 1
        }
    }
)
```

#### Score:

```
title : 10
description : 1
```

### Document:

```
db.test.insert(
  [
    { _id: 1, title: "agent de production", description: "production or agent"},
    { _id: 2, title: "agent test production", description: "agent" },
    { _id: 3, title: "production agent", "description" : "production"},
    { _id: 4, title: "agent", "description" : "production"},
    { _id: 5, title: "test", "description" : "production example agent"},
  ]
)
```

#### Question

So if I search "agent production"

Result should be

```
[
  { _id: 1, title: "agent de production", description: "production or agent"},
  { _id: 2, title: "agent test production", description: "agent" },
  { _id: 3, title: "production agent", "description" : "production"},
  { _id: 5, title: "test", "description" : "production example agent"},
]
```

#### What i had tried:

```
db.test.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "\"agent production\""}}); Query result does not match with the expected result.
```

**Result** : Nil

**Query phrase** : db.test.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "\"agent\" \"production\""}})

**Result** :

```
{ "_id" : 5, "title" : "test", "description" : "production example agent" }
{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "agent de production", "description" : "production or agent" }
{ "_id" : 3, "title" : "production agent", "description" : "production" }
{ "_id" : 2, "title" : "agent test production", "description" : "agent" }
{ "_id" : 4, "title" : "agent", "description" : "production" }
```

Any suggestion will be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried specifiying a phrase for each individual terms like `db.test.find({"$text" : {"$search" : "\"agent\" \"production\""}});`?

Comment: @chridam yeah again it not giving expected result.

Comment: We need to _see_ what happens. "not expected result" can be anything from nil to all documents.

Comment: I don't get it. The second result is what was to be expected. The document containing both search phrases are properly returned. Maybe you should add what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's review how the $search string in the [$text](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) query works.  If a phrase is given, as in `"$search": "\"agent production\""`, only documents with indexed fields matching the phrase receive a non-zero score.  That explains why no results were found in this case.  However specifying `"$search": "\"production agent\""` would match the document with `_id: 3`.  If individual words/terms are given, as in `"$search": "\"agent\" \"production\""`, any document with indexed fields matching any of the terms receive a score.  This explains why document with `_id: 4` is returned since it has the individual terms not necessarily both terms in a single field, as you have shown in your desired result.

To enforce that both search terms are included in a single field, you need to add additional clauses to the query.  You can perform the text search for scoring the documents and filter them further using regex as in:

```
db.test.find( { $and: [ { "$text": { "$search": "\"agent\" \"production\"" } },
    { $or: [
        { $and: [ { title: /agent/i }, { title: /production/i } ] }, 
        { $and: [ { description: /agent/i }, { description: /production/i } ] }
    ] }
 ] }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } ).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

Note that the textScore is added because the documents are not sorted based on score by default.